# Monitoring VPS using Cacti/Zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, vps, zabbix, cacti

I just got a VPS (CentOS on Virtuzzo) and need to monitor the load, bandwidth etc, preferably with graphs. I came across cacti, nagios, zabbix but they seem to be for monitoring large number of servers.

Since I only have a single VPS to monitor, are these suitable? Otherwise, what monitoring tools do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single server, I would suggest using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) or [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) - they both can be used to monitor multiple servers, but they're also well-suited for a single server. Much better suited than Zabbix or Nagios, for example.

Comment: I'm a Zabbix admin and I agree both monit and munin are better suited for this particular scenario. Zabbix gains on the scalability and centralized configuration over large deployments.

Comment: There is also [Monitorix](http://www.monitorix.org/) which is a lightweight system monitoring tool.